# MongoDB query for last 20(most recent) messages in ascending order

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My collection schema(which stores chat messages) is(skipping some fields):

```
timestamp_ms: epoch time to send message in milliseconds
text: string text
sender: sender id
convId: conversation id
```

When user opens a conversation, I want to show last 5 messages. So I need a query which picks most recent 5 messages and then returns them ordered by timestamp_ms in ascending order

For example if I have rows with timestamp: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 Then I want result as 5,6,7,8,9

closest query I wrote

> db.messages.find({convId:"xyz"}).sort({timestamp_ms:-1}).limit(5)

gives result in descending order(which needs to be sorted in memory) as 9,8,7,6,5. Is there any way to return these records sorted as 5,6,7,8,9

> db.messages.find({convId:"xyz"}).sort({timestamp_ms:-1}).limit(5).sort({timestamp_ms:1})

returns 1,2,3,4,5

can this be solved using aggregation pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the aggregation framework is you friend here. Something like this should work:

```
db.messages.aggregate([
    {$match: {convId:"xyz"}},
    {$sort:{timestamp_ms:-1}},
    {$limit:5},
    {$sort:{timestamp_ms:1}}
])
```